# Timeline in for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to populate a timeline using Bootstrap framework along with MVC. The information is stored in a DB and I return the data in a `Tuple<List<T>>`. Currently in my `for` loop in the view I can populate the timeline but all the items are on the left-hand side.

My question is, how can I populate the timeline so I have one item on the left and next on the right by adding the bootstrap css class `timeline-inverted`?

This is what I have at the moment.

```
for(int i = 0; i < Model.FullAttchmentList.Item2.Count; i++)
{
<ul class="timeline">
<li>
  <div class="timeline-panel">
     <div class="timeline-heading">
        <h4 class="timeline-title">@Model.FullAttchmentList.Item2[i].AttachmentName</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="timeline-body">
        @Html.Image(Model.FullAttchmentList.Item2[i].Thumbnail)
     </div>
     <hr />
     <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Download File</button>
     </div>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="timeline-inverted"> //this is where I want to add my second item
  <div class="timeline-panel">
     <div class="timeline-heading">
        <h4 class="timeline-title">@Model.FullAttchmentList.Item2[i].AttachmentName</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="timeline-body">
        @Html.Image(Model.FullAttchmentList.Item2[i].Thumbnail)
     </div>
     <hr />
     <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Download File</button>
     </div>
  </div>
 </li>
</ul>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the modulus operator to determine odd/even. Something like..

```
for(int i = 0; i < Model.FullAttchmentList.Item2.Count; i++)
{
<ul class="timeline">
  @if (i % 2 == 0) {
  <li>
  } else {
  <li class="timeline-inverted">
  }
  <div class="timeline-panel">
     <div class="timeline-heading">
        <h4 class="timeline-title">@Model.FullAttchmentList.Item2[i].AttachmentName</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="timeline-body">
        @Html.Image(Model.FullAttchmentList.Item2[i].Thumbnail)
     </div>
     <hr />
     <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Download File</button>
     </div>
  </div>
</li>
</ul>
}
```